# termplot() with plot=T and plot=F give different results from same model

Tags: r, gam

I have fit a gam with `mgcv` as `mod<-gam(y ~ s(x1) + s(x2) + year, data=df, method='REML', select=T)` and am pulling out the parametric term information with `termplot()` to create the plots by hand with ggplot.

However, when I check, I am getting different results and I don't understand why that would be.

```
termplot(mod, se = TRUE, plot = F)
$year
     x           y       se
1 2017  0.00000000 0.000000
2 2018  0.00000000 0.000000
3 2019 -1.40993696 1.130169
4 2020  0.06040809 1.252860

attr(,"constant")
(Intercept) 
  -64.06066
```

```
termplot(mod, se = TRUE, plot = T, ylim='free')
```

[image: Termplot]

I'm fitting more models for other variables of the same dataset and don't have the problem with them, i.e. the results from `termplot(mod2, plot=F)` and `termplot(mod2, plot=T)` match.

Comment: Just a guess; is `year` coded as a factor in the original data? Are the levels set correctly?

Comment: Yes, ```year``` is converted to factor in an earlier step, but I'll double-check. The weird thing is that the other two variables using the same ```year``` column end up correct, just this one doesn't. I'm trying to understand where that extra zeroes line is coming from with ```termplot(mod, plot=F)``` since it's not adding a fifth factor level with the 'missing' values, either

Comment: I changed the conversion to factor to an ordered factor and now instead of two times zeroes for 2017 and 2018, it appears to copy the values from 2018 onto 2017 instead 
```$year
     x          y        se
1 2017  0.4232074 0.7575856
2 2018  0.4232074 0.7575856
3 2019 -0.9867296 0.6705283
4 2020  0.4836154 0.7474793```
and those still don't match what is plotted with ```termplod(mod, plot=T)```